# Quickly toggling visibility of certain symbology on ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to migrate from QGIS to ArcGIS Pro (still on trial version) and I have really basic problem.

How to quick toggle visibility of object with certain symbology (unique values symbology)?

In QGIS there is option to on/of visibility for symbol of every unique attribute value on Layers Pane. However, in ArcGIS PRO there is no option like that.

Here is how it look on QGIS:

[image: QIGS]

ArcGIS Pro Contents pane:

[image: ArcGIS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that there is any way from the ArcGIS Pro GUI to do this as quickly as that.

Workarounds might be:

1. Use a definition query to filter features
2. Use Symbology pane to remove symbols

[image]

You may want to look for or submit an ArcGIS Idea.

The closest ArcGIS Idea that I have found (albeit for ArcMap rather than ArcGIS Pro) is [Make it easier to toggle different symbols on or off in the layer properties](https://geonet.esri.com/ideas/9746).

Comment: Is there any plugin/toolbox to automatically split one layer into grouped layers with query layers for every unique attribute value?

Comment: @Malauch that's a different question and one that I would need to research to answer. If there is it would probably have a name like Split Layer By Attributes.