# ArcGIS Online/ArcGIS Pro: Turn off symbol by attributes for each attribute

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

When I am working in QGIS I have the option to catogorize the symbology by attribute and that I can turn off the symbols in the layerspanel on and off easily like in the image below.

[image]

However, when I use ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS online I want to do this too. But in the contents pane there is no option for this. Is there an easy fix for this?

[image]

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Pro and mention it in your question body, but then you have ArcGIS Online and not ArcGIS Pro in your title.  Is that just a typo?

Comment: I changed it :).

Comment: I think you should focus your question on ArcGIS Pro. For that I’m confident that there is an answer and I’ll just need to remember where.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickly toggling visibility of certain symbology on ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248427/quickly-toggling-visibility-of-certain-symbology-on-arcgis-pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I don't think this functionality exists in any ESRI product. If it does, I've certainly not ever seen it. To achieve that sort of thing I've always had to use separate feature classes (or at least separate copies in the map).

This question has also been asked and answered here before it seems: [Quickly toggling visibility of certain symbology on ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248427/quickly-toggling-visibility-of-certain-symbology-on-arcgis-pro?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It does answer my question, but not as satisfied as hoped.